# How to incentivize the members of a committee voting honesty?

Tags: game-theory, voting-theory

Suppose you have a **majority** voting mechanism and a committee composed by a number of players $n$, $C = \{P_1,...,P_n\}$.
Each player is required to compute the result of a certain function $f$ and vote accordingly in case the player is honest and vote arbitrary otherwise.

In particular, the players are allowed to vote one of the following options $O = \{HO, DO_1,...,DO_k\}$, where $HO$ represents the only *honest option* (i.e., the output of $f$) and $DO_1$ to $DO_k$ represent all the possible *dishonest options*.

In order to incentivize the players to vote honestly I provide a reward $R$ to all the players who agree with the majority.

For example, suppose $C = \{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$, $f = 1$ and $O = \{1,10,100\}$. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ vote 1 and $P_3$ votes 10, both $P_1$ and $P_2$ get the reward $R$.

In general, if **no cooperation** is assumed among players, $HO$ will receive a number of votes equal to the number of honest players $|C_{honest}|$, while each $DO_i$ for $i = 1,...,k$ is expected to receive (in average) a number of votes equal to the number of dishonest players divided by the number of dishonest options $|C_{dishonest}|/k$ (i.e., the distribution of the votes of the dishonest players among the *dishonest options* is uniform).

So, as far as $|C_{honest}| > |C_{dishonest}|/k$ voting honestly is the **rational strategy** for each player.

Is this argument correct?

Instead, if a player does not know if $|C_{honest}| > |C_{dishonest}|/k$ is satisfied, then the only possible consideration, under the no cooperation assumption, is that each option is expected to receive (in average) a number of votes equal to $|C|/(k+1)$ (i.e., the distribution of the votes of the players among the options is uniform). In this case there is no rational strategy and any strategy is equivalent. Is this correct?

Another "degenerate" scenario I see is when $k = 1$ (i.e., only one *dishonest option*). In this case, having $|C_{honest}| > |C_{dishonest}|$ is required to guarantee that voting honesty is the rational strategy for each player. However, if I assume that players are composed by an honest majority, then there is no need to create an incentive to have an honest majority (since it is already an assumption) so as to have the voting mechanism selecting $HO$ as a winner.

It seems to me that when $k = 1$ the described voting and incentive mechanisms are useless. Is this correct?

If so, how can I design a voting and an incentive mechanism that implies the majority of players being honest (and does not require it as an assumption) when $k = 1$? Is it possible?

Comment: You are assuming that dishonest players choose each of the DOi options with equal probability and HO with probability 0. This could be a good assumption, depending on your objective. But it is NOT the standard approach of Game Theory. Non-cooperative Game Theory models typically specify the objectives of each player and assume that each player will try to attain their own objectives. If the players want you to believe that they are honest, then your model is similar to what is known as a Keynesian Beauty Contest. You can read more about it on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the refence. I believe that the main difference between the two models is that in my case any player can compute $f$ objectively and it is not necessary to reason on what the other players are going to vote. However, they may reason in that way if they consider if the other players are honest or not. In that case, if any option is equally likely any strategy seems to be equivalent to me. In general what I need is basically an incentive scheme that makes rational players agree on $f=HO$ or, in other words, that implies having an honest majority.

Comment: I came up with an idea. One way to always have an arbitrary $k$ may be create dummy options, i.e., different options representing the same preference.